# Creating a virtual wifi network interface for a second hostapd access point

Tags: networking, network-interface, hostapd

I'm trying to set up `hostapd` with two SSIDs. One I can do; a second is proving impossible.

My latest hypothesis is that one first has to create another of them things what appear in `ip a`, then add it to the `intefaes` file, then use it in `hostapd.conf`.
This is the command I've come up with and the problem I now have:

```
# iw dev wlx00e032800384 interface add ap2 type managed addr 02:e0:32:80:03:81
command failed: No such device (-19)
```

The adapter an eBay cheapo and is using the `rtl8821CU` driver.

**Update: configuring `hostapd`**

It looks like `hostapd` is trying to do the same thing for itself and failing for the same reason.

`hostapd.conf`

```
interface=wlx00e032800384
bridge=br0
#driver=rtl8821cu
country_code=UK
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=g
channel=9

wmm_enabled=1

# NORMAL ACCESS POINT

ssid=mini31
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=1
macaddr_acl=0
wmm_enabled=1

# OPEN ACCESS POINT
bss=ap_open

ssid=mini31_open
wpa=0 # open
macaddr_acl=1 # 1 = deny unless in accept list
accept_mac_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.accept
```

And running `hostapd` with debug messages shows up what's going on:

```
# hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
random: getrandom() support available
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1a11 subcmd=4106
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1a11 subcmd=4107
nl80211: interface wlx00e032800384 in phy phy1
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 4 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Setup AP(wlx00e032800384) - device_ap_sme=1 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x560d50976330 (device SME)
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x560d50976330 match=04
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x560d50976330 match=0501
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x560d50976330 match=0503
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x560d50976330 match=0504
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x560d50976330 match=06
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x560d50976330 match=08
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x560d50976330 match=09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x560d50976330 match=0a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x560d50976330 match=11
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x560d50976330 match=12
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x560d50976330 match=7f
nl80211: Enable Probe Request reporting nl_preq=0x560d50975b20
nl80211: Register frame type=0x40 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_PROBE_REQ) nl_handle=0x560d50975b20 match=
rfkill: initial event: idx=2 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 12 (ifidx_reason 4)
nl80211: if_indices[16]: 12(4)
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 4 (ifidx_reason -1)
nl80211: if_indices[16]: 12(4) 4(-1)
nl80211: Adding interface wlx00e032800384 into bridge br0
phy: phy1
BSS count 2, BSSID mask ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fe (1 bits)
wlx00e032800384: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Previous country code 00, new country code UK
Continue interface setup after channel list update
ctrl_iface not configured!
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=4 ifname=wlx00e032800384 operstate=6 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=4 ifname=wlx00e032800384 operstate=6 linkmode=0 master=12 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=4 ifname=wlx00e032800384 operstate=6 linkmode=0 master=12 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=4 ifname=wlx00e032800384 master=12 operstate=6 ifi_family=7 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
nl80211: Add ifindex 12 for bridge br0
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 12 (ifidx_reason 4)
nl80211: ifindex 12 already in the list
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=4 ifname=wlx00e032800384 master=12 operstate=6 ifi_family=7 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
nl80211: Add ifindex 12 for bridge br0
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 12 (ifidx_reason 4)
nl80211: ifindex 12 already in the list
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=4 ifname=wlx00e032800384 master=12 operstate=6 ifi_family=7 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
nl80211: Add ifindex 12 for bridge br0
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 12 (ifidx_reason 4)
nl80211: ifindex 12 already in the list
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=12 ifname=br0 operstate=6 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
wlx00e032800384: Event INTERFACE_STATUS (5) received
Unknown event 5
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 36 (NL80211_CMD_REG_CHANGE) received for wlx00e032800384
nl80211: Regulatory domain change
 * initiator=0
 * type=1
wlx00e032800384: Event CHANNEL_LIST_CHANGED (27) received
Channel list update timeout - try to continue anyway
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=00
nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm
nl80211: 2457-2482 @ 20 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 2474-2494 @ 20 MHz 20 mBm (no OFDM) (no IR)
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5490-5730 @ 160 MHz 20 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 57240-63720 @ 2160 MHz 0 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11g: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467[NO_IR] 2472[NO_IR] 2484[DISABLED]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11a: 5180 5200 5220 5240 5260[NO_IR][RADAR] 5280[NO_IR][RADAR] 5300[NO_IR][RADAR] 5320[NO_IR][RADAR] 5500[NO_IR][RADAR] 5520[NO_IR][RADAR] 5540[NO_IR][RADAR] 5560[NO_IR][RADAR] 5580[NO_IR][RADAR]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11b: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467[NO_IR] 2472[NO_IR] 2484[DISABLED]
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=36 freq=5180 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=40 freq=5200 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=44 freq=5220 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=48 freq=5240 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=149 freq=5745 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=153 freq=5765 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=157 freq=5785 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=161 freq=5805 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=165 freq=5825 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Completing interface initialization
Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 9  Frequency: 2452 MHz
DFS 0 channels required radar detection
nl80211: Set freq 2452 (ht_enabled=1, vht_enabled=0, bandwidth=20 MHz, cf1=2452 MHz, cf2=0 MHz)
  * freq=2452
  * vht_enabled=0
  * ht_enabled=1
  * sec_channel_offset=0
  * channel_type=1
RATE[0] rate=10 flags=0x1
RATE[1] rate=20 flags=0x1
RATE[2] rate=55 flags=0x1
RATE[3] rate=110 flags=0x1
RATE[4] rate=60 flags=0x0
RATE[5] rate=90 flags=0x0
RATE[6] rate=120 flags=0x0
RATE[7] rate=180 flags=0x0
RATE[8] rate=240 flags=0x0
RATE[9] rate=360 flags=0x0
RATE[10] rate=480 flags=0x0
RATE[11] rate=540 flags=0x0
hostapd_setup_bss(hapd=0x560d50972e80 (wlx00e032800384), first=1)
wlx00e032800384: Flushing old station entries
nl80211: flush -> DEL_STATION wlx00e032800384 (all)
wlx00e032800384: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlx00e032800384 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> -22 (Invalid argument)
nl80211: bridge FDB entry delete for ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff ifindex=4 failed: Object not found
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=4 (wlx00e032800384) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=4 (wlx00e032800384) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=4 (wlx00e032800384) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=4 (wlx00e032800384) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Using interface wlx00e032800384 with hwaddr 02:e0:32:80:03:80 and ssid "mini31"
Deriving WPA PSK based on passphrase
SSID - hexdump_ascii(len=6):
     6d 69 6e 69 33 31                                 mini31
PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=10): [REMOVED]
PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
random: Got 20/20 random bytes
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
GMK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
Key Counter - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: Delay group state machine start until Beacon frames have been configured
nl80211: Set beacon (beacon_set=0)
nl80211: Beacon head - hexdump(len=57): 80 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 02 e0 32 80 03 80 02 e0 32 80 03 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 00 11 04 00 06 6d 69 6e 69 33 31 01 08 82 84 8b 96 0c 12 18 24 03 01 09
nl80211: Beacon tail - hexdump(len=123): 07 06 55 4b 20 01 0b 14 2a 01 04 32 04 30 48 60 6c 30 14 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 02 0c 00 2d 1a 0c 00 1f ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 96 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3d 16 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f 04 00 00 00 02 dd 18 00 50 f2 02 01 01 00 00 03 a4 00 00 27 a4 00 00 42 43 5e 00 62 32 2f 00
nl80211: ifindex=4
nl80211: beacon_int=100
nl80211: beacon_rate=0
nl80211: rate_type=0
nl80211: dtim_period=2
nl80211: ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=6):
     6d 69 6e 69 33 31                                 mini31
  * beacon_int=100
  * dtim_period=2
nl80211: hidden SSID not in use
nl80211: privacy=1
nl80211: auth_algs=0x1
nl80211: wpa_version=0x2
nl80211: key_mgmt_suites=0x2
nl80211: pairwise_ciphers=0x10
nl80211: group_cipher=0x10
nl80211: SMPS mode - off
nl80211: beacon_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: proberesp_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: assocresp_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
WPA: Start group state machine to set initial keys
WPA: group state machine entering state GTK_INIT (VLAN-ID 0)
Get randomness: len=16 entropy=0
GTK - hexdump(len=16): [REMOVED]
WPA: group state machine entering state SETKEYSDONE (VLAN-ID 0)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=4 (wlx00e032800384) alg=3 addr=0x560d500ee0f0 key_idx=1 set_tx=1 seq_len=0 key_len=16
nl80211: KEY_DATA - hexdump(len=16): [REMOVED]
   broadcast key
nl80211: Set wlx00e032800384 operstate 0->1 (UP)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=4 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
hostapd_setup_bss(hapd=0x560d50974a20 (ap_open), first=0)
nl80211: Create interface iftype 3 (AP)
Failed to create interface ap_open: -19 (No such device)
Failed to add BSS (BSSID=02:e0:32:80:03:81)
ap_open: Flushing old station entries
nl80211: flush -> DEL_STATION wlx00e032800384 (all)
ap_open: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlx00e032800384 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> -22 (Invalid argument)
nl80211: bridge FDB entry delete for ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff ifindex=4 failed: Object not found
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=0 (ap_open) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-19 No such device)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=ap_open keyidx=0)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=0 (ap_open) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-19 No such device)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=ap_open keyidx=1)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=0 (ap_open) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-19 No such device)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=ap_open keyidx=2)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=0 (ap_open) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-19 No such device)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=ap_open keyidx=3)
hostapd_free_hapd_data(ap_open)
wlx00e032800384: Flushing old station entries
nl80211: flush -> DEL_STATION wlx00e032800384 (all)
wlx00e032800384: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlx00e032800384 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> -22 (Invalid argument)
nl80211: bridge FDB entry delete for ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff ifindex=4 failed: Object not found
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=4 (wlx00e032800384) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=4 (wlx00e032800384) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=4 (wlx00e032800384) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=4 (wlx00e032800384) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
hostapd_free_hapd_data(wlx00e032800384)
Interface initialization failed
wlx00e032800384: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlx00e032800384: AP-DISABLED
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x560d50971980)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=2 conf->num_bss=2
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x560d50971980)
wlx00e032800384: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss ap_open
ap_open: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlx00e032800384 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> -22 (Invalid argument)
nl80211: bridge FDB entry delete for ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff ifindex=4 failed: Object not found
ap_open: AP-DISABLED
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x560d50974a20 (ap_open))
ap_open: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface ap_open wasn't started
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlx00e032800384
wlx00e032800384: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlx00e032800384 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> -22 (Invalid argument)
nl80211: bridge FDB entry delete for ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff ifindex=4 failed: Object not found
wlx00e032800384: AP-DISABLED
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x560d50972e80 (wlx00e032800384))
wlx00e032800384: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlx00e032800384 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=0x560d50172840 drv_priv=0x560d50976750 -> hapd_deinit
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlx00e032800384 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Disable Probe Request reporting nl_preq=0x8888de85d81fd3a9
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
nl80211: Remove beacon (ifindex=4)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=4 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 4 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Teardown AP(wlx00e032800384) - device_ap_sme=1 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Unsubscribe mgmt frames handle 0x8888de85d81febb9 (AP teardown (dev SME))
hostapd_interface_free(0x560d50971980)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x560d50972e80
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x560d50974a20
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x560d50971980)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x560d50971980)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x560d50971980
```

See the

```
... 
hostapd_setup_bss(hapd=0x560d50974a20 (ap_open), first=0)
nl80211: Create interface iftype 3 (AP) 
Failed to create interface ap_open: -19 (No such device)
...
```

Comment: an equivalent command here works (I mean only that `iw` creates the interface). You could also try `phy phy0` (or phy1 if 2nd wireless nic etc) instead of `dev wlx00e032800384`. If still not working you should check your NIC's capabilities: `iw phy phy0 info`. Look what's below `valid interface combinations:`.

Comment: Tried the `phy` version. Same result. No _valid interface combinations_ in `iw phy phy1 info`.

Comment: Aha! `interface combinations are not supported`. What does that mean?

Comment: I want two APs. I thought it could be done as two SSIDs on one channel, but none if the hostapd configs I've tried have worked.

Comment: Do I want to combine anything? For two APs?

Comment: here's an example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401464/deciphering-the-output-of-iw-list-valid-interface-combinations so you get an idea. This person can't use two APs in the first given combination. but in the 2nd example given, two APs are possible. In your case, there's no combination, so what do you expect?

Comment: a typical ATH9K (the power of having no firmware locking capabilities): * #{ managed } <= 2048, #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match

Answer (score 1):

If the Wi-Fi card supports it, you will have to add the second virtual interface to the physical interface. The iw command you were using was attempting to add a second managed interface to the virtual interface. In the end, you want a second AP interface to the phy. Your card may also have a MAC reserved so try without assigning the MAC.

```
iw phy0 interface add ap0 type __ap
```

Note, there are two underscores in "__ap" and ap0 is just an arbitrary name for the virtual interface.

Comment: I'm getting `command failed: Operation not supported (-95)` when I try this. Any idea why?

Comment: Your chipset likely does not support multiple virtual interfaces.